# ruby rr: How to stub/mock built-in variables like $?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking, rr

While writing a unit test for following:

```
def foo()
  popen_response = ""
  IO.popen(@packaging_cmd, :err=>[:child, :out]) {|io| popen_response = io.read }
  rc = $?
  @log.debug{"Response from IO.popen() : #{popen_response}. rc: '#{rc}'"}
  if rc.exitstatus != 0
    @log.error{"Packaging failed. rc: '#{rc}'"}
    raise PackagingError.new("Packaging failed. rc: '#{rc}'")
  end
end
```

I'm stuck because I don't know how to mock/stub what `$?` evaluates to. I can hack around by creating a function that returns `$?` and mock that function or tinker with teh command passed to `IO.popen()`, but I wonder if there is any official way in RR that I can use.

I'm using `rr` with stock `Test::Unit::TestCase`

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'rr'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which mocking framework you are using, but in RSpec:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Process::Status).to receive(:exitstatus).and_return(0)
```